# SyntaxError nodeJS

Tags: node.js

I host a NodeJS discord bot on termius but when I type certain codes and I start the bot, I get this error and I really want to fix this please help

`````
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47````
`````

Comment: That only looks like a partial error. What's the actual error message? And the code that causes it?

Comment: The "type certain codes" is probably a hint at what code to look at.  This part of the stack trace looks like it is attempting to dynamically load some module which contains a SyntaxError.  The next step is to figure out which module is being dynamically loaded and contains the error.